# How to access a module inside of a module from a file inside the first module in python?

Tags: python, file, module, file-io, operating-system

I have the following file format and I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uploader'

```
Video-Generator/
    main.py
    AutoUploader/
        __init__.py
        upload.py
        uploader/
            __init__.py
            myfile.py
```

Essentialy, I am trying to access uploader from upload.py that is being called from main.py.
That is when I get that error which originates from upload.py unable to find the module.

In main.py, I have the following to access the AutoUploader module:

```
from AutoUploader import *
from AutoUploader.upload import upload_video_from_json
```

And in upload.py, I have the following to access the uploader module:

```
from uploader import myfile
```

Thanks in advance to all your help!

Comment: Use a relative import: `from .uploader import myfile`.

Comment: tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Explain "didn't work". What is the error message?

Comment: I get the exact same error message as before: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uploader'

Comment: Alternatively you can try `from AutoUploader.uploader import myfile`. Does this work?